# If statement not executing when in a timer. (Form Sizes)

Tags: c#, winforms, timer

Alright so basically I've tried fixing this every possible way I know how. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong here, this should work...

```
private void Main_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Size = new Size(0,0);
        timer2.Enabled = true ;

    }

    public void timer2_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Width += 20;
        this.Height += 20;

        if (this.Height == 400)
        {
            timer2.Enabled = false;
        }
```

In the grand scheme, I'm resizing the form 20px at a time at an interval of 100ms.

EDIT: This is me trying, very crudely, to make a form animation.

Comment: What's the value of this.Height initially set too?

Comment: what is timer interval ?

Comment: It is originally at 400,400, but as you can see in the Main_load, I set it to 0,0 to start off. I added the interval, it's 100ms. Yes it does fire. it just doesn't stop which is what the if statement is meant to stop.

Comment: not very much to go on, what are your observations? does it fire? did you debug?

Comment: Try to slow down your timer. It is a bit freaking fast. Also put a System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(this.Height) at the timer event entry

Comment: Yes it does fire. I tried using Message boxes to see what was going on with the form sizes and it doesn't come out correctly. Let's say it was supposed to be 40, it would be 48.

Comment: why not try this.Height >= 400 as condition?

Comment: Can you tell if the timer2 always remain enabled or is disabled as soon as you run the program? Can you please elaborate as what is the outcome of the above error...

Comment: You might want to check `this.MinimumSize`. It's quite possible that the form won't go smaller than that, which will break your `if` statement. Or you can write `if (this.Height >= 400)` ...

Answer (score 2):

You should maybe correct your if-statement using greater than:

```
public void timer2_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Width += 20;
    this.Height += 20;

    if (this.Height >= 400)
    {
        timer2.Enabled = false;
    }
}
```

Good luck with your quest.

Comment: I face-palmed when I read this, such a little oversight. However now, yes the timer does now stop, but it stops much bigger than 400 which is what I wanted it to be. It overshoots by quite a bit.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void timer2_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    if (this.Height < 400)
    {
        this.Height += 20;
        this.Width += 20;   

    }
    else
    {
        timer2.Enabled = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: This seems to be the most secure way to ensure that it stops at the point required however it still overshoots, I added a messagebox to see what was going on and it continually stops at 418 Height and 512 Width. I'm starting to think that maybe it's a WinForm limitation. Seems WPF would be better for my animation needs.